# Vba: Delete excel sheets not mentioned in the list (the list only contains numeric value)

Tags: excel, vba

I need to delete sheets not mentioned in the given list(Range is A7:A350).
I found this vba but the problem is it deletes all the sheets from my workbook, maybe because sheetname is in numeric. I would really appreciate any help.

```
Sub Deletenotinlist()
Dim i As Long
Dim cnt As Long
Dim xWb, actWs As Worksheet
Set actWs = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
cnt = 0
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
For i = Sheets.Count To 1 Step -1
    If Not ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i) Is actWs Then
        xWb = Application.Match(Sheets(i).Name, actWs.Range("A7:A350"), 0)
        If IsError(xWb) Then
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Delete
            cnt = cnt + 1
        End If
    End If
Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
If cnt = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Not find the sheets to be seleted", vbInformation, "Kutools for Excel"
Else
    MsgBox "Have deleted" & cnt & "worksheets"
End If
```

End Sub

Comment: Are you sure that sheets name you do not want to be deleted really exist in that range?

Comment: You said: *maybe because sheetname is in numeric* Yes that seems to be the reason. I tested, and a sheet name like `2021` listed in the worksheet just like that (as the number 2021) did not match with the worksheet `2021`. I then selected the range with those names and selected `Format` - `Text` and the sheet names become left aligned, but still did not match the sheet names. Finally I added a single tick mark (apostrophe) in front of the name ('2021) and now it worked. The single tick mark does not show up in the worksheet, but there will be the green error indicator in the left top corner.

Comment: Hi @FaneDuru, yes all the sheets exist in that range.

Comment: Hi @TomBrunberg, I tried to add apostrophe into my list and it worked! Thanks so much for your comment!

Answer (score 0):

I think I would do it this way.

```
Sub DeleteSheets()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range

Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A10")
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Application.CountIf(rng, sht.Name) = 0 Then
        sht.Delete
    End If

Next sht

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried to test it, but the only the sheet where the sheet names are listed is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

What you try doing can be accomplished in many ways, but I tried adapting your code to place the missing sheets name in an array and select them at the end. If selection is convenient, you can replace `Select` with `Delete`:

```
Sub Deletenotinlist()
 Dim i As Long, cnt As Long, xWb, actWs As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arrSh(), k As Long

 Set actWs = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
 lastR = actWs.Range("A" & actWs.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
 ReDim arrSh(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.count - 1)
 cnt = 0
 For i = 1 To Sheets.count
    If Not ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i) Is actWs Then
        xWb = Application.match(Sheets(i).Name, actWs.Range("A7:A" & lastR), 0)
        If IsError(xWb) Then
            arrSh(k) = CStr(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name): k = k + 1
            cnt = cnt + 1
        End If
    End If
 Next
 ReDim Preserve arrSh(k - 1) 'keep only the filled array elements
 Sheets(arrSh).Select 'You can replace 'Select' with 'Delete', if it returns correctly

 If cnt = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Not find the sheets to be seleted", vbInformation, "Kutools for Excel"
 Else
    MsgBox "Have deleted " & cnt & " worksheets"
 End If
End Sub
```

It processes all existing values in column A:A, starting from the 7th row.

But I'm afraid that the range you try processing does not contain any existing sheet name...

In order to test the above supposition, please run the next test sub, which will place all existing sheets name in column B:B, starting from the 7th row. Then delete some rows and run the previous code, replacing "A" with "B"   in `lastR = actWs.Range("A" &...` and `actWs.Range("A7:A" & lastR)`. The code should select all missing sheets:

```
Sub testArraySheets()
  Dim arrSh, ws As Worksheet, k As Long
  
  ReDim arrSh(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.count - 1)
  For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
       If Not ws Is ActiveSheet Then
            arrSh(k) = ws.Name: k = k + 1
       End If
  Next
  ActiveSheet.Range("B7").Resize(UBound(arrSh) + 1, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(arrSh)
End Sub
```

Comment: the above code cannot read my list because it is written in numbers which result to selection/deletion of all the sheets into my workbook. but I find the testarraysheets() very useful! thank you FaneDuru!

Comment: Don't you have the sheets **name**? If names, even numeric, the code should work. I am driving now. I will reply after some hours...

Comment: the sheet names are just numbers from 1 to 350. I tried to convert my list into text and add an apostrophe in front of each numbers and the finally, the code was able to read my list and it was able to match it with the given sheets. Now I was able to delete unnecessary sheets. It`s ok, drive safe!

Comment: @hiro  Not need to adapt the records in the sheet. The code should be adapted in order to convert them in strings when putting in the array. I will adapt the code to do it... Adapted. I did not know that the names are numbers. Please, test the updated version and send some feedback.

Comment: I tried to test it but the result is the same. it selects/deletes all my sheets.